# Is there any way to know from which domain the socket.io connection is coming from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I would like to know from which domain a socket.io client is connnected from.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // I want to know from which domain this client is connected from, in here...
});
```

Comment: You mean you want to know *which website (domain) the browser that’s establishing the connection is currently visiting*?

Comment: Yeah, exactly...